# Existe el siguiente problema de comprobación con mysql_insert_id?

Tags: php

Tengo una duda sobre si para conseguir el resultado que voy a detallar a continuación, es eficaz.

Imagínate el supuesto de que tienes un formulario, rellenas los campos, y das a aceptar, y, por tanto, ejecutas un insert, por ejemplo:

```
$prueba = "INSERT INTO cliente (nombre_cliente, cif, direccion, email) VALUES ('xxx Nombre empresa', 'B3331113', 'C/ Corona 2', 'eepe@relll.com')";
```

Inmediatamente una vez ejecutada la consulta y creada, quisiera obtener el id de cliente que se acaba de crear. Para aclarar un poco las cosas, la tabla constaría de las siguientes columnas: id_cliente; nombre_cliente; cif; direccion; email.

He leído que para obtener la última consulta he de usar mysql_insert_id($conexión), y así me funciona, es decir, que me obtiene la id del último registro, ahora, esa id que he obtenido la quiero meter en el campo de otra tabla, es decir, hacer otro insert a continuación del que he detallado, y una vez sacada la id de la fila creada en el primer insert.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, imagina el supuesto de dos usuarios que dan a aceptar y crean el cliente a la misma hora, minutos, segundos... ¿Sería posible que con mysql_insert_id($conexión) pillase mal el id_cliente? Es decir, que pillase el del otro usuario que está creando el usuario a la misma hora, minutos, segundos... en el segundo insert? porque si el código se ejecuta a la vez, ¿no podrían confundirse?

Expresado en código para que me entiendas bien

```
$prueba = "INSERT INTO cliente (nombre_cliente, cif, direccion, email) VALUES ('xxx Nombre empresa', 'B3331113', 'C/ Corona 2', 'eepe@relll.com')";

$ultimo_id = mysql_insert_id($connectid); 

$test = "INSERT INTO test (id_cliente) VALUES ('$ultimo_id')";
```

En mi cabeza suena tal que, me imagino un usuario que da a crear el usuario, pero se le ralentiza el internet, y otro que lo hace al mismo momento, y por un instante se adelanta al primero que ha ejecutado hasta el primer insert, como se ha adelantado el segundo al primero, el primero leería el mysql_insert_id de forma errónea ¿o no depende la lectura del código de la velocidad de internet? No sé si me explico... Muchas gracias.

Comment: El valor del último id insertado se limita a la conexión; considera que PHP puede manejar [*Conexiones persistentes*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.persistent-connections.php).

Comment: Quizá la duda surge al pensar que los registros de la tabla se crean en términos de hh:mm:ss. ¿Por qué no lo piensas mejor como una cola, donde empezarán a entrar las diferentes solicitudes de inserción? Si hay dos solicitudes, originadas a la misma hh:mm:ss entrarán ambas en la cola. Cuál entre primero no interesa aquí, serán **dos solicitudes distintas** y cuando ellas ocurran, se generará un `ID` que será el último **para la conexión que solicitó el insert**. Es así como funciona, no hay confusión posible en esto. Ten en cuenta que esto sólo aplica si la tabla tiene un `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Por otra parte, lo que describes en tu código no es algo que deberías resolver a nivel de PHP, sino a nivel de la base de datos, programando un [disparador (`TRIGGER`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html), que haga la inserción en la tabla `test` cuando un `INSERT` ocurra en la tabla `cliente`. De todo se encargará la BD, sin tener que romperte el coco de si hay dos usuarios o un millón de usuarios concurrentes.

Comment: @Sal Gracias por tu comentario :)

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por la explicación exhaustiva, me ha ayudado mucho ^^. Lo que no entiendo muy bien es lo último que has dicho, de que eso se debería manejar por los disparadores, y no entiendo el motivo. Es decir, yo tengo un formulario html, y el código de funcionamiento en php. Cuando das clic se activa el código en PHP, ¿eso no es correcto? Por otro lado el mensaje me confunde, es decir, me dices que no habrá problemas en el primero, pero en el segundo mensaje entiendo que dices que únicamente no me dará problemas si es por trigger. Espero me lo puedes aclarar, graciaaaas.

Comment: Quizá no me expliqué bien. Tú puedes hacerlo perfectamente desde PHP, pero una base de datos no es solamente un almacén de datos, es mucho más y dispone de herramientas muy poderosas para realizar tareas que de otro modo habría que reprogramar en otros entornos, con el consiguiente riesgo de errar en el código y dañar datos, etc. Este puede ser uno de esos casos. Supongamos que por cada inserción en `cliente` debes insertar un registro en `test`. Pues si programas un `TRIGGER` en la base de datos, esa inserción se hará de forma automática, sin que tú tengas que programarlo en PHP.

Answer (score 0):

En una base de datos distribuida podrías tener ese tipo de problema, pero tienen mecanismos para solventarlo.

En un único servidor, en este caso MySQL que ya implementa accesos concurrentes y multitarea, tampoco debería preocuparte.

En la parte que a ti podría afectarte, piensa que tienes esa variable `$connectid` que diferenciará un `INSERT` del otro. Y, en el caso de que hagas ambos desde la misma conexión, necesariamente los harás en orden.

Espero haberte respondido. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Uso mysql, entonces entiendo que no deba tener problemas de ese tipo, ¿correcto? Gracias ^^

Comment: Eso es, afortunadamente, no eres el primero que se ha encontrado con este problema :) Quédate tranquilo, que funciona

Answer (score 0):

Quizá la duda surge al pensar que los registros de la tabla se crean en términos de horas, minutos y segundos. Sí, los datos se crean en un momento determinado, pero ¿hay dos momentos iguales en la vida? Más allá de los segundos, todavía existen unidades de medida, por ahora hemos llegado hasta el [*zeptosegundo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeptosegundo), que constituye la miltrillonésima parte de un segundo.

¿Por qué no lo piensas mejor como una cola<sup>1</sup>, donde empezarán a entrar las diferentes solicitudes de inserción? Si hay dos o más solicitudes de inserción, originadas a la misma hora, minuto y segundo y la miltrillonésima parte de éste, todas esas solicitudes entrarán en la cola. Podemos ilustrar esta afirmación con este párrafo del [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/concurrent-inserts.html):

> The `MyISAM` storage engine supports concurrent inserts to reduce
> contention between readers and writers for a given table: If a
> `MyISAM` table has no holes in the data file (deleted rows in the
> middle), an `INSERT` statement can be executed to add rows to the end
> of the table at the same time that `SELECT` statements are reading
> rows from the table. If there are multiple `INSERT` statements, they
> are queued and performed in sequence, concurrently with the `SELECT`
> statements. The results of a concurrent `INSERT` may not be visible
> immediately.
>
> ---
>
> El motor de almacenamiento `MyISAM` admite inserciones simultáneas
> para reducir la contención entre lectores y escritores para una tabla
> determinada: si una tabla `MyISAM` no tiene agujeros en el archivo de
> datos (filas eliminadas en el medio), se puede ejecutar una
> instrucción `INSERT` para agregar filas al final de la tabla al mismo
> tiempo que las declaraciones `SELECT` leen filas de la tabla. Si hay
> varias declaraciones `INSERT`, se ponen en cola y se ejecutan en
> secuencia, al mismo tiempo que las declaraciones `SELECT`. Es posible
> que los resultados de un `INSERT` simultáneo no sean visibles de
> inmediato.

Cuál entre primero no interesa aquí, serán dos solicitudes distintas y cuando ellas ocurran, se generará un ID que será el último para la conexión que solicitó el insert. Si hay `N` clientes haciendo inserciones, cada uno recibirá **su último ID**, porque, siempre [según el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), `LAST_INSERT_ID()` funciona **por conexión**:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
> ***per-connection basis***. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first `AUTO_INCREMENT` value
> generated for most recent statement affecting an `AUTO_INCREMENT`
> column ***by that client***. This value cannot be affected by other
> clients, even if they generate `AUTO_INCREMENT` values of their own.
> This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without
> concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for
> locks or transactions.
>
> ---
>
> La ID que se generó se mantiene en el servidor ***por conexión***.
> Esto significa que el valor devuelto por la función a un cliente
> determinado es el primer valor `AUTO_INCREMENT` generado para la
> declaración más reciente que afecta una columna `AUTO_INCREMENT`
> ***por ese cliente***. Este valor no puede verse afectado por otros clientes, incluso si generan sus propios valores `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
> Este comportamiento garantiza que cada cliente pueda recuperar su
> propia identificación sin preocuparse por la actividad de otros
> clientes y sin necesidad de bloqueos o transacciones.

Es así como funciona, no hay confusión posible en esto. Sin olvidar que `LAST_INSERT_ID()` sólo funciona en aquellas tablas que tienen declarada una columna `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Por otra parte, lo que describes en tu código no es algo que deberías resolver a nivel de PHP (aunque no hay ningún problema en hacerlo si quieres), sino a nivel de la base de datos, programando un [disparador (`TRIGGER`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html), que haga la inserción en la tabla `test` cuando un `INSERT` ocurra en la tabla `cliente`. De todo se encargará el SGBD, sin tener que romperte el coco de si hay dos usuarios o un millón de usuarios concurrentes o perder el tiempo programando código para reinventar la rueda, o exponer los datos a errores originados en ese código.

Por ejemplo, si tú programas un `TRIGGER` para este caso, y tu aplicación está escrita para varias plataformas (Web, Móviles, PHP, Java, C, Phython...), en cualquiera de esas plataformas que ocurra un `INSERT` en `cliente`, el `TRIGGER` hará la inserción en `test`. En cambio, si lo haces tú, reinventando la rueda, tendrás que escribir código para cada plataforma (Web, Móviles, PHP, Java, C, Phython...), manejar el `INSERT` en `test`, etc, etc. Si hay un error en algunos de esos códigos, ese error se propagará en los datos.

Es importante comprender que un SGBD no es simplemente un almacén para meter datos, sino todo un sistema con herramientas poderosísimas para automatizar casi todo tipo de tareas relativas al manejo de esos datos.

---

### Notas

1. `INNODB` funciona de otro modo, pero ese no es el tema principal de debate aquí. Pero, si quieres profundizar en el tema, puedes leer [esta entrada del Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-performance-thread_concurrency.html).